# Count specific lines in text file

Tags: php, count, lines

How to count specific lines in a text file depending on a particular variable in that line.

For example i need to count the lines of a text file only containing for instance $item1 or $item2 etc.

Comment: That is nice...so the question?

Comment: @KA_lin looks like you didn't read the thread title.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need something like what `grep -c` do in the shell, try something like this:

```
$item1 = 'match me';
$item2 = 'match me too';

// Thanks to @Baba for the suggestion:
$match_count = count(
    preg_grep(
         '/'.preg_quote($item1).'|'.preg_quote($item2).'/i',
         file('somefile_input.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
    )
);

// does the same without creating a second array with the matches
$match_count = array_reduce(
    file('somefile_input.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES),
    function($match_count, $line) use ($item1, $item2) {  
        return 
            preg_match('/'.preg_quote($item1).'|'.preg_quote($item2).'/i', $line) ?
            $match_count + 1 : $match_count;
    }
);
```

The above code sample uses the [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to read the file into an array (splitted by lines), [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to iterate that array and [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) inside the iteration to see if a line matched (the `/i` at the end makes it case-insensitive).

You could use a foreach as well too.

Comment: @Baba, Good call, i guess simply slipped my mind, added to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i still can't get this to work right :(... i'm using /t as a spacer for the variables in my txt file.  basically i'm trying to return 100 lines/results per page based on $item1 or $item2... any suggestions. Ty.

Comment: @user1634119, sounds like you have a [tsv file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values), try using the various csv processing functions like [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) with your delimiter. Also if you are using a flat file as a database, i would consider using a real database system with sql support if possible.

Comment: right now I’m using array_slice to chop the txt file into 100 line sections... but i really need it to only count the lines that contain either $item1 or $item 2 Etc. I'm really lost on this one. The other answers seem like they should work but no luck yet. :( lol

Answer (score 1):

This code reads `file.php` and counts only lines containing `'$item1'` or `'$item2'`. The check itself could be finetuned, since you have to add a new `stristr()` for every word you want to check.

```
<?php

$file = 'file.php';

$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$size = filesize($file);
$content = fread($fp, $size);

$lines = preg_split('/\n/', $content);

$count = 0;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(stristr($line, '$item1') || stristr($line, '$item2')) {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read your file line by line and use strpos to determine if a line contains a specific string/item.

```
$handle = fopen ("filename", "r");
$counter = 0;
while (!feof($handle))
{
  $line = fgets($handle);
  // or $item2, $item3, etc.
  $pos = strpos($line, $item);
  if ($pos !== false)
  {
    $counter++
  }
}
fclose ($handle);
```